# Running multiple shell commands inside perl script

Tags: perl, shell, command

I am using `System()` command to execute shell command from perl script but I need to run multiple commands one after another. How can we do that in one line.

What I am doing currently is :

```
$cmd = "ls -l cd /home/xyz ls -l" , 
System($cmd)
```

I am sure that single command works fine , Can someone let me know if this is right way to do? if not what is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the same thing that you would in your shell. For your test command, it would look something like:

```
$cmd = "ls -l ; cd /home/xyz ; ls -l";
system($cmd);
```

Or better yet, as suggested by [BadFileMagic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623728/badfilemagic):

```
$cmd = "ls -l ; cd /home/xyz && ls -l";
```

This way, the second `ls` is not executed if the `cd` fails.

Comment: it probably doesn't matter in such as simple example as this, but using && instead of ; is better when stringing commands together, especially of the execution of the next is dependent on successful completion of the command preceding it.